# When we take curl of a vector field is it not affected by any singular point unlike divergence of that field?

Tags: vectors

In $(r, \theta, \phi )$ coordinate system $\nabla\cdot\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}=4\pi\delta^3(\vec{r})$ . There is this $\delta^3(\vec{r})$ because $\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$ blows up at point $r=0$

But $\nabla\times\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}=0$ instead of the fact that $\frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$ blows up at $r=0$

Another example from $ (\rho,\phi,z)$ co-ordinate system $\frac{\hat{φ}}{\rho}$ blows up at $\rho =0$ , however $\nabla\times\frac{\hat{φ}}{\rho}=0$ .

My question is When we take curl of a vector field is it not affected by any such singular point unlike divergence of that field? What is happening here?

Comment: $\nabla \times \hat{\phi}/\rho$ is not zero but a delta function at $\rho=0$.